# MYSQL 8.0 Whats wrong with SELECT COUNT * query?

Tags: mysql

i have problem with my query for mysql 8.0. Trying to find whats wrond. Here is my query:

```
"SELECT""threeid,"fourid","fiveid",""(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "test_table" WHERE id=_t.twotid AND threeid=_t.threeid AND fou=_t.fourid AND fiveid=_t.fiveid AND sixid=_t.sixid) AS example ""FROM "test_table" AS _t WHERE firstid=%i AND twoid=%i%s ""GROUP BY threeid,fourid,fiveid ""ORDER BY threeid"
```

I have error with this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near. How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the rest of the error message? There should be a string or a line number after "syntax to use near". Also, what are you using to inject the variable values within the `WHERE` clause of the outer query?

Comment: After syntax to use near: 'example  FROM test_table AS _t WHERE firstid=1 AND twoid=1 GROUP BY threeid, fourid, fiveid ORDE' at line 1

Comment: What are all the double quotes in the query? It should look something more like `SELECT threeid,fourid,fiveid,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_table WHERE id=_t.twotid AND threeid=_t.threeid AND fou=_t.fourid AND fiveid=_t.fiveid AND sixid=_t.sixid) AS example FROM test_table AS _t WHERE firstid=%i AND twoid=%i%s GROUP BY threeid,fourid,fiveid ORDER BY threeid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need any count alongside other columns, use COUNT(*) or COUNT(Expression) alongside column names instead of SELECT(COUNT(....), avoid using nested sub-queries wherever possible .

Let me give an example to show you how I  implemented what you wanted.

Working query :

SELECT tmc AS Defaulter,attdate, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfTimesBefore5 FROM ru WHERE before5='1' GROUP BY tmc ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;

I have used this query to find out how may times people in my organization have left before 5pm by their punch-out time.
Here, tmc is like a unique identifier for all entries,attdate i sthe timestamp of punch-out , before5 is like a flag having value 1 only where people have punched out before 5pm.

Coming back to your question, directly type COUNT(*) alongside column names followed by conditions, you can use GROUP BY and ORDER BY wherever needed.

Comment: @Termoline I hope your issue is solved, please let me know if you need any other help.